# passing generic iterator to function cpp

Tags: c++

Trying to send an iterator function using Template, that can get any iterator (from array, queue, etc..). [in the example, I send vector]

THE ERROR: line 15 not compile:

```
ExampleVector <int> vec(values.begin(), values.end())")
```

```
template <typename ExampleVectorType>
class ExampleVector //new  class
        {
            template <class InputIterator> // generic iterator
            ExampleVector (InputIterator& first, InputIterator& last) // constructor (do nothing)
            {
            }
        };
int main()
{
    /* Create the values */
    std::vector<int> val{4, 8, 12};
    /* Create the vec */
    ExampleVector <int> vec(val.begin(), val.end());
}
```

Comment: Although the problem seems to be fairly basic, the very fact that the code that was initially posted had misnamed variables, it means that even after correcting the variable names the shown code is still not the real code you're trying to compile, the problem could be something else entirely. This is why stackoverflow.com tells you to show a [mre], instead of fake code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing one compile time error after another I get this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
template <typename ExampleVectorType>
class ExampleVector //new  class
        {
            public:
            template <class InputIterator> // generic iterator
            ExampleVector (const InputIterator& first, const InputIterator& last) // constructor (do nothing)
            {
            }
        };
int main()
{
    /* Create the values */
    std::vector<int> val{4, 8, 12};
    /* Create the vec */
    ExampleVector <int> vec(val.begin(), val.end());
}
```

The errors and solutions are:

1. `values` ==> `val`
2. missing `public:` before the constructor
3. You cannot pass an rvalue to a function, which expects an lvalue reference, therefore I changed the function to get `const` lvalue references.